# System.Security.HostProtectionException when Executing User Defined Function on SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I wrote a User Defined Function that gets a UtcTimeStamp and a windowstimezoneid as parameters and returns the TimeStamp for the TimeZone.

But if i want to execute it in a simple select i get the following error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ToLocalTime": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: MayLeakOnAbort

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
   bei TimeFunctions.ToLocalTime(DateTime UtcTimestamp, String WindowsTimeZoneId)
```

I execute the select as sa. I set clr enabled to  1. I use SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600).

Does anyone know what i have to set to get this working or what i may done wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CLR assemblies have [trust levels.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx)

This one requires UNSAFE permissions because of the rights required to use "MayLeakOnAbort"

Either change the CLR to something safer, or re-add the assembly with UNSAFE rights. The word "UNSAFE" is exactly that of course...

Comment: thanks had to set trustworthy on first and changed the database owner to sa, but now it works with unsafe.

Comment: @gbn I have created assembly and also given Unsafe permission there But still getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found that changing a HashSet to a List in my CLR code made this issue go away. Have no idea why that is. Hopefully that might help someone.

Comment: Had to found this by myself, but I think this one deserves to be upvoted so people know about this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of types and members that the CLR will reject because they MayLeakOnAbort, note this URL is for SQL 2017.

[MayLeakOnAbort Members and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-security-host-protection-attributes/disallowed-types-and-members-in-system-core-dll?view=sql-server-2017)

So check if you are using any of those and see if you can change it.  Otherwise you will have to mark UNSAFE or something similar