# Getting error when using UDF with SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclr

I have made a CLR by using SQL Project Templates into Visual studio using language C# as::

```
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()]
    public static SqlDateTime ScalarUDF(SqlInt64 CompanyID)
    {
        SqlInt64 temp = CompanyID;
        string zoneId = "Singapore Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
        DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi);

        return new SqlDateTime(result);
    }
```

And also created the UDF into SQL using query::

```
-- Install Assembly
CREATE ASSEMBLY UDF_Trial FROM 'C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\UDF_Trial\UDF_Trial\bin\Debug\UDF_Trial.dll'
GO
-- Create ScalarUDF
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ScalarUDF](@CompanyID bigint)
RETURNS datetime
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME UDF_Trial.UserDefinedFunctions.ScalarUDF;
GO
```

But while Executing the UDF I am gettin some Error:

I am executing UDF as,

`select [dbo].[ScalarUDF](15)`

But Getting the Exception as::

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ScalarUDF": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: MayLeakOnAbort

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
   at UserDefinedFunctions.ScalarUDF(SqlInt64 CompanyID)
.
```

I have also made the Permission to `UNSAFE` at the time of creating Assembly as::

CREATE ASSEMBLY UDF_Trial FROM 'C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\pro_temp\UDF_Trial.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
GO

but in this case I am getting Error as::

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'UDF_Trial' failed because assembly 'UDF_Trial' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE.  The assembly is authorized when either of the following is true: the database owner (DBO) has UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568751/system-security-hostprotectionexception-when-executing-user-defined-function-on

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou Give the Proper answer instead of looking into another's answer.

Comment: Read the StackOverflow guidelines before asking questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Answer (score 3):

I have set the Trustworthy of the Database to ON as::

```
ALTER DATABASE Learn SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

and have created Assembly as ::

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY UDF_Blog FROM 'C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\UDF_Trial\UDF_Trial\bin\Debug\UDF_Trial.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
GO
```

and the Problem is solved.